# Создание grid сетки с разной высотой

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, css-grid

Собственно, что хочу и что получаю: [image: grid сетка]

```css
.grid { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: start;
  }
.grid > article {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px  rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.grid > article img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.text {
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
}
.text > button {
  background: gray;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<main class="grid">
  <article>
    <img src="https://www.quackit.com/pix/samples/23m.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Seamlessly visualize quality</h3>
      <p>Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks.</p>
      <button>Here's why</button>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://www.quackit.com/pix/samples/24m.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Completely Synergize</h3>
      <p>Dramatically engage seamlessly visualize quality intellectual capital without superior collaboration and idea-sharing.</p>
      <button>Here's how</button>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://www.quackit.com/pix/samples/22l.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Dynamically Procrastinate</h3>
      <p>Completely synergize resource taxing relationships via premier niche markets.</p>
      <button>Read more</button>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://www.quackit.com/pix/samples/15l.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Best in class</h3>
      <p>Imagine jumping into that boat, and just letting it sail wherever the wind takes you...</p>
      <button>Just do it...</button>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://www.quackit.com/pix/samples/25m.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Dynamically innovate supply chains</h3>
      <p>Holisticly predominate extensible testing procedures for reliable supply chains.</p>
      <button>Here's why</button>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img src="https://www.quackit.com/pix/samples/16l.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Sanity check</h3>
      <p>Objectively innovate empowered manufactured products whereas parallel platforms.</p>
      <button>Stop here</button>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

Новостной сайт, такие "карточки" подгружаются постоянно при скролле главной страницы вниз. Размеры самих картинок одинаковые, а вот заголовок и описание разной длинны. От чего эти карточки больше или меньше по высоте?

Comment: Вот при такой задаче, вроде, используют flex-боксы.

Comment: Может быть у вас есть какой-то пример?

Answer (score 5):

То что вы ищите гуглится в сети по запросу `Grid CSS Pinterest Layout`. Добавил первый же попавшийся код для примера:

```css
@font-face{font-family:'Calluna';
 src:url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/callunasansregular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
body {
 background: url(//subtlepatterns.com/patterns/scribble_light.png);
  font-family: Calluna, Arial, sans-serif;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
#columns {
 column-width: 320px;
 column-gap: 15px;
  width: 90%;
 max-width: 1100px;
 margin: 50px auto;
}

div#columns figure {
 background: #fefefe;
 border: 2px solid #fcfcfc;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
 margin: 0 2px 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
}

div#columns figure img {
 width: 100%; height: auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

div#columns figure figcaption {
  font-size: .9rem;
 color: #444;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

div#columns small { 
  font-size: 1rem;
  float: right; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #aaa;
} 

div#columns small a { 
  color: #666; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  transition: .4s color;
}

div#columns:hover figure:not(:hover) {
 opacity: 0.4;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) { 
  #columns { column-gap: 0px; }
  #columns figure { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="columns">
  <figure>
  <img src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/cinderella.jpg">
 <figcaption>Cinderella wearing European fashion of the mid-1860’s</figcaption>
 </figure>
 
 <figure>
 <img src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/rapunzel.jpg">
 <figcaption>Rapunzel, clothed in 1820’s period fashion</figcaption>
 </figure>
 
  <figure>
 <img src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/belle.jpg">
 <figcaption>Belle, based on 1770’s French court fashion</figcaption>
 </figure>
  
 <figure>
 <img src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/mulan_2.jpg">
 <figcaption>Mulan, based on the Ming Dynasty period</figcaption>
 </figure>
 
   <figure>
  <img src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/sleeping-beauty.jpg">
 <figcaption>Sleeping Beauty, based on European fashions in 1485</figcaption>
 </figure>
 
   <figure>
  <img src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/pocahontas_2.jpg">
 <figcaption>Pocahontas based on 17th century Powhatan costume</figcaption>
 </figure>
  
 <figure>
 <img src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/snow-white.jpg">
 <figcaption>Snow White, based on 16th century German fashion</figcaption>
 </figure> 
  
   <figure>
 <img src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/ariel.jpg">
 <figcaption>Ariel wearing an evening gown of the 1890’s</figcaption>
 </figure>
  
    <figure>
 <img src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/tiana.jpg">
    <figcaption>Tiana wearing the <i>robe de style</i> of the 1920’s</figcaption>
 </figure> 
  <small>Art &copy; <a href="//clairehummel.com">Claire Hummel</a></small>
 </div>
```

[Источник](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/yqrhw)

Если допустимо использование JS, то можете также воспользоваться для удобности [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Займусь изучением.

Comment: Но лучше использовать js Masonry

Comment: @VladimirRodichev я б только так и делал ) и указал про Mansory. Но надо было показать, что есть и другие выходы из ситуации

Comment: А почему лучше?

Comment: @SoreThursday удобнее. У меня была подобная ситуация, тоже много гуглил, пробовал разные варианты, но пришёл все-таки к Mansory в моём случае. Там готовая библиотека, ничего не надо выдумывать

Comment: @SoreThursday ответ решил вашу задачу?

Comment: А с тем вариантом, что вы предложили с помощью CSS думаете возникнут какие-то проблемы?

Comment: @SoreThursday нет, не возникнут, с чего бы. Если вёрстка нормальная будет. Я в ответе написал по какому запросу гуглить, по этому запросу есть ещё и другие решения, я просто показал первое адекватное.

Comment: Пока еще не знаю, решил или нет. Занимаюсь.

Comment: @SoreThursday Тогда удачи, дерзай. У меня тоже сегодня `grid` на повестке дня )))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91290/discussion-between-sorethursday-and-l-f-c).

Comment: @L.F.C. Да, читал. П.с. я один из первых вам плюсик поставил.